# Make link with specific id open in new window with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a CMS where **I cannot change the html**. But they do give the ability to add javascript to the page.

There's a link in the usual format
e.g. `<a id="myid" href="">Link</a>`

What's the best way to open this in a new window?

(It is on a page with a form. So it's one occasion where forcing a new window is definitely required to keep the text filled in on the form from being cleared by a change of page)

Comment: Add target attribute with value _blank like this, ```target="_blank"```. visit https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp for more info

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the ability to change the html. So I can't add target="_blank" to the a element.

Comment: Yes, it's surprising that some missed that limitation since it's clearly stated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't set `target` attribute on the `<a>` tag but you can set an id, then this code should work:

```js
document.getElementById('idOfLinkYouWantToOpenInADifferentWindow').target = '_blank';
```

If you can't add an ID, then you can target `href` directly, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('a[href=https://www.google.fr/]').target = '_blank';
```

Comment: Up vote because this answers the question of how content editors, with limited rights, can customize generated html.  It's a common problem in enterprise CMS environments.

Comment: Thanks! I added another solution targeting href directly by editing my answer.